# Hide button based on class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a button if it has a class "List" and if not display it. On load itself I'm displaying the button, and later if that has a class, I'm hiding it using jquery. It works too!. But I'm not sure that it is the best way to do it. Any suggestions? Here is my code

```
$('.ProductList').parent().find('.CompareButton').show();
   if($('ul.ProductList').hasClass('List')) {
           $(this).find('.CompareButton').hide();
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this part

```
$(this).find('.CompareButton').hide();
```

into:

```
$('.CompareButton').hide();
```

Comment: You just made my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think `$(this)` will refer to `$('ul.ProductList')` as per your given code.

you may have to try out

```
$('ul.ProductList').find('.CompareButton').hide();
```

instead of

```
$(this).find('.CompareButton').hide();
```

Comment: @Sateesh, No. I need to check if <ul class='ProductList'> has that class, then only I need to hide it.

Comment: @NizamAli : I am not telling you to remove all code. just that the `$(this)` u are refering to will not refer to the object you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The easily thing is add to your css 2 statement one without class `list` `display:block` & One With class `list` `display:none`like this . 
 when you add  the class. Statement 2 will be Evaluted
& when you removed Statement 1 will be Evaluted.

```
ul.ProductList.List  {display:block}
ul.ProductList.List .CompareButton {display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default if you want to display it then assign display:block in your html code, later on ready document you can call a function to hide it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
showButton();

});

function showButton() {
if($('ul.ProductList').hasClass('List')) {
           $(this).find('.CompareButton').hide();
   } 

}
```

Comment: I shouldn't write any code on HTML code. I need to write only in JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery code can be at least shortened a bit.

```
// this can be shown in css by default
$('.ProductList').parent().find('.CompareButton').show(); 
//this replaces your if statement
$('.ProductList.List').parent().find('.CompareButton').hide();
```

But better way would be to hide what you need in css without using javascript at all.

Comment: The condition is I shouldn't use any css code or any HTML code. So, that's why I need to check it using IF condition

Comment: `$('.ProductList.List')` would select `ul` that has both `.ProductList` and `.List`, isnt that what you want?

Comment: I need to check whether <ul class='ProductList'> it has the class 'List' or not. If not then I shouldn't compile that statement. I hope that makes sense :)